# Adding a calculated metric to a custom report in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

Is there a way to display a calculated field in a `custom report`, for example I want to display the value of (event X / event Y) over time? 
(including `average event value`, `total events`, etc.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, I don't think that Google Analytics offers calculated fields yet. You'll need to extract your data via the [reporting API](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/home.html), then manipulate it using Excel or a database.

If you don't want to write code to use the API directly, there are tools available that you can use to extract your data: For example, [Excellent Analytics](http://excellentanalytics.com/), is a free tool for downloading Analytics data into Excel.

Comment: Thanks, too bad this simple feature isn't supported by Google analytics. Will check out Excellent Analytics

Comment: I just read this comment, watched the video on this page and built the report that I was looking for within 15 minutes, it's pretty simple. Link: https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/google-analytics-spreadsheet-add-on

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that stumbles upon this question, [Google Analytics now offers Calculated Metrics](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6121409?hl=en).